# C++ помогите найти ошибку в коде

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы

Нужно вывести на экран числа имеющиеся в двух массивах

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int mass1[6]= {4,3,7,9,1,6};
    int mass2[6]={};
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    { cin>>mass2[i];}
    cout<<"числа которые находятся в обоих массивах: ";
    for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
     {for (int j=0; j<6; i++)
      {if ( mass2[i]==mass1[j])
        cout<<mass2[i];} 
     
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему ты решил, что тут ошибка?

Comment: Программа не работает

Comment: Почему ты думаешь, что не работает, а не просто не выводит ничего?

Comment: Действительно не выводит, но не могу понять почему

Comment: Ну видимо совпадений нет ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Дело в том, что были. Программа не выводит

Comment: Вниамтельно посмотри на строку с счётчиком `j` (в for) ....... (об этой проблеме должна сообщить твоя IDE !)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас во внутреннем цикле должна увеличиваться переменная j, а Вы увеличиваете i.
У вас:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
     {for (int j=0; j<6; i++)
```

Правильно должно быть так:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
     {for (int j=0; j<6; j++)
```